# how to get individual values from this array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this result when I printed the array print_r($post);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subscriber_id] => 80010055 [cto_id] => [name] => n [mobile] => 1234564444 [state] => [city] => fsd [cto_subscriber_id] => 0 [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e [email] => n@n.com [email_verified] => 1 [ip_address] => ::1 [last_login_time] => 2012-10-24 11:37:19 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subscriber_id] => 80010055 [ip_address] => [landline_number] => [sex] => 0 [dob] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [marital_status] => hfg [state] => [addres] => fgh [city] => fghfg [pincode] => fghfgh ) ) )
```

How can I get single values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach $post as $sub {
    foreach $sub as $single {
        echo $single;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typecast it to array?

```
$arr = (array)$post[0][0];
```

And then you'll be able to loop through it as through normal array

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you should learn the basics of [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) first.
Anyway in order to get the value of lets say subscriber_id you should use the following:

```
$post[0][0]->subscriber_id
```

First you get into the array and then get the value out of the Object